# UTF-8 encoding with FileBody in MultipartEntity

Tags: android, multipartentity

I want to set UTF-8 encoding while files sending in FileBody as I do it in a StringBuilder. I do it like this:

```
restClient.AddEntity("body", new StringBody(body, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```

and it works properly if I send different from UTF-8 messages encoding. But if I do like this:

```
ContentBody fbody = new FileBody(( File )file, "application/octet-stream","UTF-8");
        restClient.AddEntity("files[]", fbody);
```

server get files names not in UTF-8. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solve this issue simply, by:

```
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE,null,Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

Answer (score 3):

I solve this issue, by this params:

```
entity.addPart("video_title", new StringBody(edtvideo_title.getText().toString(),Charset.forName(HTTP.UTF_8)));
```